# Android database table not created

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqlexception

In Android, I'm having difficulties finding out what is the problem with the following query. The coding seems correct. I'm trying the following snippet:

```
 DATABASE_TABLES.add("CREATE TABLE PageRights("
                +"RightsId INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +"PageName varchar(-1) NULL,"
                +"PageId INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +"UserId INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +"RoleId INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +"Add BOOLEAN NOT NULL,"
                +"Edit BOOLEAN NULL,"
                +"Delete BOOLEAN NULL,"
                +"CreatedBy varchar(-1) NULL,"
                +"CreatedDate DATE NOT NULL,"
                +"Views BOOLEAN NULL)");
```

The error being thrown is ;

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Add": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE PageRights(RightsId INTEGER NOT NULL,PageName varchar(-1) NULL,PageId INTEGER NOT NULL,UserId INTEGER NOT NULL,RoleId INTEGER NOT NULL,Add BOOLEAN NOT NULL,Edit BOOLEAN NULL,Delete BOOLEAN NULL,CreatedBy varchar(-1) NULL,CreatedDate DATE NOT NULL,Views BOOLEAN NULL)
```

Please help me by giving your idea .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Add"

`Add` is a reserved word in MySQL. So are `Edit` and `Delete` by the way.

Change the names of those columns to something else.

Answer (score 5):

`Add`,`Edit`,`Delete` are pre-defined keywords, use following way,

```
DATABASE_TABLES.add("CREATE TABLE PageRights("
                +"RightsId INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +"PageName varchar(-1) NULL,"
                +"PageId INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +"UserId INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +"RoleId INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +"Add_PageRights BOOLEAN NOT NULL,"
                +"Edit_PageRights BOOLEAN NULL,"
                +"Delete_PageRights BOOLEAN NULL,"
                +"CreatedBy varchar(-1) NULL,"
                +"CreatedDate DATE NOT NULL,"
                +"Views BOOLEAN NULL)");
```

Please visit [Oracle naming standards tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/standards_schema_object_names.htm).